# Passing a string from one page to another in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

All i want is to pass my Entry Text from one page to another. Not in `Xaml` but in `.cs` file.

**First page code**

```
<Label Text="Username" TextColor="Gold" FontSize="Small"/>
<Entry Placeholder="Username" TextColor="White" x:Name="Username"/>
```

`Username.Text` will be used for the Text. I want this text on my second page.

Second page where i want this `Username.Text`

```
sqlcmd.CommandText = queryString;
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", {I want Username.Text here });
```

Thank You.

Comment: Try sqlcmd.CommandText = queryString;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n",Username.Text.Trim());

Comment: a Page is just a class.  You pass data to it like you would to any class instance - via the constructor, a public property or method, etc

Comment: I have used everything. Still it's giving me null value on the other page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this depending on how you have structured your app.

If the page is already open you can use [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/) to send from one `ViewModel` or `Page` To the other

**Sender**

```
MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, "Hi");
```

**Receiver**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, "Hi", (sender) => {
    // do something whenever the "Hi" message is sent
});
```

If you are creating the `Page`, you can just pass in the text through the Page `Constructor`,

**New Page Constructor**

```
public MyPage(string someText)
{
}
```

**Sender**

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new MyPage(<YourTextHere>)));
```

or via a `Property`

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new MyPage() { SomneProperty = "blach" ));
```

**Additional Resources**

[Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushAsync Method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.INavigation.PushAsync/p/Xamarin.Forms.Page/)

[How the MessagingCenter Works](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/messaging-center/)

Comment: I can't use the constructor to send the value because I'm using the tabbed page. I'll try messaging center and then let you know.

Comment: For Messaging Center I'm using    MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage> (this, Username.Text);     And for receiving I'm using   MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage> (this, Username.Text); but here i can't access Username.Text

Comment: I have to send this value to the second page of my Tabbed Page. That is why i can't use the constructor.

Comment: Did it with 2 constructors on 2 pages :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So i had a Tabbed Page with 5 pages in it. What i did is this.

Passed my Username.Text like this

```
 Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Overview(Username.Text));
```

Then retrieved it like this in the Overview Page.

```
 public string str = null;
    public Overview (string g)
    {
        str = g;

        this.Children.Add(new Home()
        {
            Title = "Home",
            Icon = "",
        });
        this.Children.Add(new EarnPoints(str)
        {
            Title = "Earn More",
            Icon = "",
        });
```

And then finally in my EarnPoints page i did this.

```
 public string sts = null;
    public EarnPoints (string g)
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        sts = g;

        GetAccountCountFromMySQL();  
    }

    public void GetAccountCountFromMySQL()
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlConnection sqlconn;
            string connsqlstring = "Server=lightningstorerewards.com;database=sukree_dzgpt;User Id=sukree_gptuser;Password=kgausi9nMNzX;charset=utf8";
            sqlconn = new MySqlConnection(connsqlstring);
            sqlconn.Open();
            string queryString = "SELECT points FROM users WHERE username = @n";
            MySqlCommand sqlcmd = new MySqlCommand(queryString, sqlconn);
            sqlcmd.CommandText = queryString;
            sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", sts);
```

Thanks for all your help :)